# docker COPY failed: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

I am trying to copy my project into app folder.

Dockerfile

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04
    RUN mkdir /app
    ARG input_project_path
    COPY $input_project_path /app
```

When I run the docker build command it returns the following error and I am running the docker build command in the same directory as my Dockerfile.

```
ubuntu:~/$ sudo docker build --build-arg input_project_path=/home/ubuntu/web-app/ -t test .

COPY $input_project_path /app
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder055576899/home/ubuntu/web-app/: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all the files/directories that you want to use in `COPY` in the same directory where your `Dockerfile` is present.

Comment: if i specify the relative path it works.  docker build --build-arg input_project_path=./web-app/ -t test .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
COPY ${input_project_path} /app
```